# how can i get recent chat of a user from coreData swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities Friend and Message
now i want to get the latest message of friend how can i do this

Friend contain these things

```
Friend{
  name:String
  id:Int
  email:String
}
```

and Message Contain these thing and also have one to many relationShip from friend to message

```
   Message{
     id:String
     text:String
     created_at:Date
     /...// and many things

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest message of user by sort Descriptor like this:-

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>.init(entityName: "Message")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "created_at", ascending: false)]
let predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "friend.id = %@","1")// pass the id of friend for you want to access latest message
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

now you can fetch this request